# How to change the Link path value Using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have a `JSON` data provides below link.

https://www-quicker.cna.com/profiles/html/profileView.do?userid=qui9090

But  we need to change the link as we mention below,

https://www-quicker.cna.com/profiles/photo.do?userid=qui9090

I need to change "**/html/profileView.do?**" insead of "**/photo.do?**"

We try with filters i cant find any good method.

**HTML :**

```
  <div ng-repeat="x in todos.records">
     <p>{{x.Name | ifLink}}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: what is your problem then? filter is not working? Or you are in search of more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need `filter` in this case, update HTML to:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in todos.records">
  <p>
   {{(x.Name === '/photo.do?') ? '/html/profileView.do?' : x.Name}}
  </p>
</div>
```

For `a` tag with `href` attribute:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in todos.records">
    <a href="{{(x.Name === '/photo.do?') ? '/html/profileView.do?' : x.Name}}">Photo</a>
</div>
```

***Note***: `Name` is property with `url` value.

Comment: Give me your sample json data?